# Setting up Google Cloud DNS for beginner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I am very new to Google Cloud DNS or networking related stuff .

I setup my server for hosting, Now I want to setup my DNS server for managing sub domains and other records .
**Question First**

My first question is: Do I have to create different zones for different websites in Google Cloud DNS?

e.g.

*www.xyz.com & www.abc.com (require new) or both can be managed in same zone and record set. If yes any short description would help me .*

**Initial setup**

I have gone through [these](https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart) steps and created record for my [website](http://www.bandbaaja.in).

I have few more questions:

1. How do I create sub-domain records properly?

My Setup

[image: Setup]

Updated : Question put to point

Answer (score 2):

You will need separate zones for www.abc.com and www.xyz.com.

You can use the same zone for www.abc.com and m.abc.com; unless they need separate servers you can use the same CNAME alias target for both.

Answer (score 0):

How to set up a Cloud DNS managed zone and a resource record for your domain name. It walks through a simple example on setting up a Cloud DNS managed zone and then setting up Address (A) and Canonical Name (CNAME) records for the domain. Please see below procedure on how to set up Cloud DNS managed zone, A record and CNAME records:

Create a managed public zone [1].

A managed zone is a container for DNS records of the same DNS name suffix. A managed zone has a set of name servers that accept and responds to queries. Create a new managed public zone [1]:

The Zone details page is displayed. Note that default NS and SOA records have been created for you. Once you have the list of your NS record you need to update your NS record on your Domain registrar. NS record for Cloud DNS should be the same on your Domain Registrar.

Create a new record for A record [2].

Create a CNAME record [3].

The record update will take some time to propagate depending on the time-to-live (TTL) values in your zone. You can verify that the DNS records are working by visiting the domain name and confirming that the domain resolves to your IP address.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_managed_public_zone

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_new_record

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_cname_record

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do i create subdomain records properly

So you want to create sub-domain. Follow below steps to set DNS for sub-domain

1. First open Cloud DNS under Network services
2. Click to zone name that you used for NS record
3. Now click on 'Add Record Set' button to create new NS record set for your sub-domain
4. First create 'A' record and type your sub-domain name in 'DNS Name' and enter your IP address(Main instance ip address i.e. your IPv4 address is 104.199.119.40) in IPv4 address. Second create 'CNAME' record set and type your sub-domain name like 'www.sub' in 'DNS Name' add Canonical Name(your main domain name) shiftboolean.com

The record update will take some time to propagate depending on the TTL values in your zone. I hope this will helpfull for you. Let me know if you need any help regarding DNS record set for sub-domain.  I'm using above mentioned step and successfully create my sub-domain on google cloud platform.